# Не работает библиотека xNet

Tags: c#, dll, xnet

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Собрал и подключил библиотеку xNet, качал с github, но она почему-то не работает. Вот такой простой код из примера:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    //request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();

    HttpResponse response = request.Get("https://wtfismyip.com/text");
    string content = response.ToString();
    label1.Text = content;
}
```

выдает исключение xNet.Net.HttpException - не удается подключиться. Хотя Интернет работает и HTTPWebRequest работает отлично. Выдает исключение на любом сайте.

Visual Studio 2013 .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: .NET 4.5.5 не бывает.

Comment: Поправил пост, не знаю чего не бывает, знаю только то, что есть.

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко: А гугл качается? Или лучше какая-нибудь страница, не требующая https?

Comment: Неа, только что попробовал, никакую страницу не грузит. Я вот думаю, может я неправильно собрал или подключил? Я новичок в этом деле, может где и оплошал.
Собрал, открыв в VS проект xNet.csproj, и нажал "Собрать решение". Потом в обозревателе решений добавил в References xNet.dll, который создался в папке Release.

Comment: Попробуйте эту версию: https://www.sendspace.com/file/q58o9q

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужно использовать именно эту библиотеку? Сам автор пишет, что создавал её ещё до появления `System.Net.Http` и возможно там вы найдёте всё что вам нужно.

Comment: @beta-tank, библиотека рабочая, неоднократно проверенная. Любят эту либу за удобство использования.

Comment: @z668, к сожалению, по неизвестной мне причине ,и Ваш вариант не работает. 
У меня удобство на втором плане, вообще ищу библиотеку для использования Socks4 и Socks5 прокси, может подскажете какие есть другие?

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко, У вас там случайно нет прокси сервера для выхода в интернет? Возможно требуется добавить, что-то типа `request.Proxy = new HttpProxyClient("proxy", 8080, "user","pass");`

Comment: @cybrex, нет, соединяюсь через ADSL-роутер, без прокси. При этом HTTPWebRequest работает. Наверное действительно что-то в системе.

Comment: Может кто подскажет, что может быть в системе?

Я только что посмотрел внимательнее, до этого исключения несколько раз вызывается и перехватывается вот такое исключение:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: "Предпринятая операция не поддерживается для выбранного типа объекта"